# Difference between SDL_RenderSetClipRect and SDL_RenderSetViewport

Tags: sdl, sdl-2

What is the difference between [`SDL_RenderSetClipRect`](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_RenderSetClipRect) and [`SDL_RenderSetViewport`](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_RenderSetViewport). Those two wiki pages have a slightly different wording, but they seem to have the same meaning.

Most of the tutorials I have seen, they use viewports to draw differently on the screen. I plan to use it to draw onto textures which are clumped together into a few big atlas textures. However, either of the above functions alter the "current/specified target" of the renderer, which can be a texture.

Comment: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/40704/what-is-the-purpose-of-glscissor since this are the functions SDL2 opengl accelerated backend uses.